# p:inputSwitch primefaces cambiar etiqueta

Tags: primefaces

estoy trabajando con el componente `p:inputSwitch` de primefaces 6.2, por defecto el componente para el estado activo/inactivo tiene las etiquetas `on/off` ¿Cómo cambiar esos nombres?

```
<p:inputSwitch value="#{selectBooleanView.value1}" />
```

[Página oficial](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputSwitch.xhtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la documentación esto debería funcionarte.

```
<p:inputSwitch value="#{selectBooleanView.value1}" onLabel="chachi que si" offLabel="chachi que no"/>
```

https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/inputswitch